# I need to install a P-trap but the pipe coming out of the wall has no threads on it and is 1 1/4 wide and is very short. How do I secure a new pipe

Tags: sink, bathroom-fixtures

The pipe from the wall is 2 inches long with no thread on it. How to I attach new pipe to it?

Comment: what kind of pipe is in the wall?

Comment: A picture of the pipe will help a lot.  Different types of pipe have different ways/adapters for joining.

Answer (score 1):

Two choices

Find and glue on a adapter. When glueing do not forget to put the nut first the right way.

or use 1-1/4 inch rubber hose with clamps on both ends